# Yii 403 on Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii, http-status-code-403

I have a page which lists ticket/queries made by users.  Each ticket has associated notes which i want to display when a user clicks on a ticket. (I want to use a CJuiDialog for this).

To save page loading time, I want to use ajax to fill the dialog's .

I'm using the following code, which always returns the error: "else: undefined".  Chrome's console however returns the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl("tblTickets/AjaxDialog"); ?>',
    type: "POST",
    data: {tno: tid},  
    error: function(xhr,tStatus,e){
        if(!xhr){
            alert(" We have an error ");
            alert(tStatus+"   "+e.message);
        }else{
            alert("else: "+e.message); // the great unknown
        }
    },
    success: function(resp){
        alert('success');  // deal with data returned
    }
});
```

Is there something extra I need to get it to work?

**EDIT:** I made an addition to the accessRules which resulted in a change.  No longer do I get a 403 error but a 500 error.
I am new to Yii, I'm trying to call a function within the TicketsController called actionAjaxDialog via ajax.

**EDIT2:** Okay 500 error was caused by the PHP function it was calling.  The ajax appears to be working now!
But I am still have a problem.  I cannot get it to pass the data.  I always get an 'undefined index' error

Comment: Check wheather the link is working correctly ??

Comment: hi, See edit of original post

Comment: I have just tried this, was updating my post as you posted.  I found the issue causing the 500 error.

Comment: There is no longer a 500 error. My issue now is that I cant seem to get it to send data that 'tid' variable is a id number that I need to use

Comment: 'tid' changes. It's passed to a js function by an onclick. I've just got it working by adding "&tno='+tid" to the end of the url.

Comment: Then you have to get that tid value from url in javascript variable and then pass that variable to ajax data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the way to do this.  The Ajax was fine.

Instead inside the Controller I needed to update the accessRules function, adding 'ajaxdialog' to the allowed actions for the correct user group

```
array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
    'actions'=>array('index','view','ajaxdialog'),
    'users'=>array('*'),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

We are using this below code like:

```
<?php
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
    $.ajax({
                    url: '".Yii::app()->createUrl("/invoice/create")."',
                    data:'tid='+tname,
                    success: function(){
                      alert('success');
                      return false;
                    }
               });
");
?>
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi, this code works, as in I no longer get forbidden errors.  But it calls at page load.  How can I call it when an element is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

try this it works for me

```
 $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/controllername/actionname');?>",
            data:{},//data for throwing the expected url
            type:"POST",//you can also use GET method
            dataType:"html",//you can also specify for the result for json or xml
            success:function(response){
                 $('#news').html(response);
            },
            error:function(){
                 alert("Failed request data from ajax page");
            }
        });
```